# How do I add a search funtion to my discord music bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to add a search function to my discord music bot however my little knowledge in pyhton is hindering me frm doing so.

I would like to make is so that whenever someone puts in chat: ?search (song name)

it would play the song in the voice channel.

I have watched this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM) and added some of my own little tweaks, however that is all.

I have tried looking at other stack overflow pages but io dont know how to tweak their code to work with mine, any help? Ty

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import  commands
import youtube_dl
from requests import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
      self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
       if ctx.author.voice is None: 
         await ctx.send("ur not in a vc bruv")
       voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
       if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect() 
       else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        
    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options':'-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
          info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
          url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
          source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(info['formats'][0]['url'], before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5")
          vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def search(self,ctx):
      YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
           await ctx.send("paused bro")
           await ctx.voice_client.pause()

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
            await ctx.send("resumed bro")
            await ctx.voice_client.resume()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the youtube api to search for url's, and then use something like YTDL to play based on URL

docs --> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3